# avconv: getting aac to work. -strict experimental doesn't work

Tags: aac, avconv

I am trying to get the following screencast command to work:

```js
avconv -f alsa -ar 44100 -ac 2 -i default -acodec aac -strict experimental -ab 320k -f x11grab -s 1024x600 -r 24  -i :0.0  -vcodec rawvideo screencast.mp4
```

But I still get the following error:

> encoder 'aac' is experimental and might produce bad results.
>   Add '-strict experimental' if you want to use it

Other sites suggest making sure that the -strict experimental appears immediately after the aac parameter, which I have done, to no effect.

Answer (score 24):

Move both the `-acodec aac` and `-strict experimental` to somewhere after the last `-i` parameter in the command line, before the output file name.

Parameters to avconv are parsed as "avconv *[input1 options]* -i input1 *[input2 options]* -i input2 *[output options]* outputfile", so when you added these parameters before the second `-i` they were interpreted as options to the second input, not to the output.

Comment: let me rephrase: `-strict experimental` should be on the output, because the encoder is experimental; the aac decoder isn't, so don't use it for aac inputs